# Invert order of nested cell arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I would like to know if it is possible to invert the order of nested cell arrays in Matlab.

If I have a cell array
`A{a,b}{c,d}`
is there a way to convert it into
`B{c,d}{a,b}`
?

The aim is to get
`C={c,d}(a,b)`
to be able to sum over a and later over b.

If I do
`C=cellfun(@cell2mat, A, 'UniformOutput', false);`
then C will have a shape `C{a,b}(c,d)`, which doesn't help me further.

I would appreciate any help, tips or comments.

Anna

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if your `A` varaible has numbers or even more nested cells at the `A{a,b}{c,d}` level, but if we assume single numbers in a cell you could make this in 2 short steps

1. Flatten your cell
2. Built it up in re-arrange order

Let's first create some test data. To easy the code verification each value is build by information about its original position/index by the pattern: `ab.cd`. For example `A{1,4}{2,3}` is given the value `14.23`.

```
% Index size
a = 5;
b = 4;
c = 3;
d = 2;

% Cell values
[ai, bi] = ind2sub([a b], 1:a*b);
abVal = 10*ai + bi;
[ci,di] = ndgrid(1:c,1:d);
cdVal = ci/10+di/100;

% Built up A
A = cell(a,b);
for i = 1:numel(A)
    A{i} = num2cell(abVal(i) + cdVal);
end
```

The `num2cell` is really not needed here, but is there to better mimic your data. If you have number (not cells) or deeper nested cells, you might have to use parentheses `(:)` instead of curly brackets `{:}` in the last line below. But for this example the following does it.

```
% Flatten the 2-level nested cell  (could use vercat instead of horcat)
A_flat = horzcat(A{:});
A_flat = horzcat(A_flat{:}); % Could also use [A_flat{:}] here
```

Now use the fact that values are placed at an even index distance and pick out evere `c x b` value.

```
% Built up re-arrange cell
A_reOrdered = cell(c,d);
for i = 1:c*d
    A_reOrdered{i} = reshape(A_flat(i:c*d:end), a, b);
end
```

Here, I have actually transformed from `A{a,b}{c,d}` to `A{c,d}(a,b)`. If you want a cell structure at the bottom i.e. `A{c,d}{a,b}`, just put a `num2cell` before the `reshape` in the `for`loop

For some example valus:

```
>> A_reOrdered{3,1}
ans =
        11.31        12.31        13.31        14.31
        21.31        22.31        23.31        24.31
        31.31        32.31        33.31        34.31
        41.31        42.31        43.31        44.31
        51.31        52.31        53.31        54.31

>> A_reOrdered{3,1}(5,2)
ans =
        52.31
```

which was originally placed at

```
>> A{5,2}{3,1}
ans =
        52.31
```

---

But if the aim really was to calculate some sum, you could stop after the flattening step and operate on that data directly. Study the pattern of `A_flat` and I think you'll see it.

For example to sum all values for a specific 'b'

```
nB = a*c*d;
for ib = 1:b
    bSum(ib) = sum(A_flat((ib-1)*nB + (1:nB)));
end

% ... or without the for-loop
bSum = arrayfun(@(x) sum(A_flat(x + (1:nB))), nB*(0:b-1));

bSum =
       936.45       966.45       996.45       1026.5
```